# Google+ Sign-In hybrid with spring-security

Tags: spring-security, google-plus, google-openid

to enabling OpenID authentication with Spring Security
 We can add OpenID to the login page as follows:
`

```
<form action="j_spring_openid_security_check" method="post">
<input name="openid_identifier" size="50" maxlength="100"
type="hidden" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign in with Google"/>
</form>
```

for migrating to Google+ Sign-In how to integrated it  with *following* HTML sign-in button?

```
    <span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

this solution not work

```
<form action="<c:url value='j_spring_openid_security_check'/>"
        method="post">
        <input id="openid_identifier" name="openid_identifier" type="hidden"
            value="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" />
        <input name="scope" value="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
            type="hidden" />
        <input name="response_type" value="code" type="hidden" />
        <input name="client_id"
            value="*****************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            type="hidden" />
        <input name="client_url" value="**********" type="hidden" />
        <input name="redirect_uri" value="postmessage" type="hidden" />
        <input name="origin" value="**********" type="hidden" />
        <input id="openid_submit" type="submit" value="Sign-In" />
    </form>
```